# Cannot view mail contents

Tags: gmail, osx-mountain-lion, safari

I have a very strange issue with Gmail. When trying to view the contents of an email I end up having a screen like below:

[image: Email Contents]

I have tried disabling all extensions, one-by-one, while viewing Gmail but did not have a different result. The email is rendered perfectly in Firefox and Chrome.

What could be causing this issue? From my basic search online, I might be the only person having this issue.

Comment: Try reading emails on Gmail using 64-bit Safari [src:https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3801881?start=0&tstart=0]

Comment: @sabrefresco thanks for the suggestion but it is already running as 64-bit: [activity monitor](http://d.pr/i/HEyM) and [get info screen](http://d.pr/i/7b7f).